# Newly added element not getting updated in html

Tags: angularjs

I have this controller code:

```
$scope.searchResult = [{title:"this is 1"},{title:"this is 2"}];

$scope.searchByTag = function()
{
    $location.path("search");

    var req = {                   
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'url',
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': "application/json"
       },
       data: searchFormService.getTagSearhReqData()
    };

    $http(req).then(function(d){          
      for(var i=0;i<d.data.length;i++)
      {
        $scope.searchResult.push(d.data[i]);              
      }          
      alert($scope.searchResult.length);
    }, function(e){
    });     
}
```

Here is html code:

```
    <div ng-repeat="data in searchResult">
            {{data.title}}
    </div>
```

Initially it show `title1` & `title2` when `searchByTag()` is called the `alert($scope.searchResult.length);` show new length of `searchResult` that means new element got added to `searchResult` but it is not updated in html.

Comment: Your code should work, but maybe it hangs on the alert (until you press OK)? Try to comment out the alert or convert it to a `console.log` and see what happens. Or maybe `d.data[i]` does not contain the `title` property? You can `console.log(d.data[i])` to check that.

Comment: inside loop `console.log(d.data[i].title);` works well & i tried to without alert also

Comment: can you share the jsfiddle ?

Comment: Then the only other suspect is `$location.path("search");`. What's that for? What if you comment it out?

Comment: on button click inside a search form page i call `searchResult` and inside that i want to jump to `search` page to show the result.

Answer (score 0):

your JSON structure is like that

```
$scope.searchResult.push({'title':d.data[i]});
```